# Asp.net MVC Nhibernate not gathering selected items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, razor

When the user selects items in roles and submits the model is not populated with the selected items. Can i please get some insight if I should be doing this another way.

Model

```
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual int FailedAttempts { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Login user)
    {
        var u = repoLogin.Update(user);
        repoLogin.Save(u);

        return View(u);
    }
```

View

```
        <label>Roles</label>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Roles, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(LiveReport.Domain.Enum.UserRoles))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Role` is a complex object. A ListBoxFor sends a list of simple strings corresponding to the values being selected.

So you could have a property which will hold the selected values:

```
public virtual IList<string> SelectedRoles { get; set; }
```

and then bind the select list to it:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    m => m.SelectedRoles, 
    new SelectList(
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(LiveReport.Domain.Enum.UserRoles))
    )
)
```

Also you seem to be using some enum to populate the select list items. So you could use this same enum as property to bind the list to:

```
public virtual IList<UserRoles> SelectedRoles { get; set; }
```

Comment: That still does not bind them, using that none of the roles on the user are selected within the users listbox of roles.